# Stack with a nested map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stack

I'm writing a small program in c++:

```
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std ; 
int main() {
    stack< map<string,int> > st ; 
    map<string,int> ma ; 
    st.push(ma) ; 
    ma = st.pop() ;  // error here 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

But the compiler shows the error:

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘ma = st.std::stack<_Tp, _Sequence>::pop<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>, std::deque<std::map<std::  

basic_string<char>, int>, std::allocator<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int> > > >()’
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Please make sure you've studied a library reference in detail before posting such questions. This is all [*very* well documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop).

Comment: I'm sorry, should I just delete this question?

Comment: Up to you. There are definitely tons of duplicates of it, and it's extremely unlikely that the question title will be helpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`std::stack::pop`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) does **not** return the removed value. You'll have to first assign the [`top`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) value and then call [`pop`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop), on the stack, to remove it:

```
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::stack<std::map<std::string, int>> st; 
    std::map<std::string, int> ma; 
    st.push(ma); 
    ma = st.top();
    st.pop(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

If you don't believe me: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b6be3e32b92c538)'s the live example.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stack<>::pop` does not return a value.  You need to call `top` instead, *before* you call pop.

```
ma = st.top();
st.pop();
```

Actually, since you are about to pop the element off anyway, it would be better to use `std::move` if you are using C++11.

```
ma = std::move(st.top());
st.pop();
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to edit this I meant to edit mine :| not sure how to "rollback"

Comment: Oh,right! by the way, the last line is st.pop(). Thanks for your help!